# What does RETURN TRUE do in a php function?

Tags: php, cakephp

I was just looking at this code and i don't understand what RETURN TRUE does or what the point of it is? Can someone please explain?

```
class Elephpant {

    public $colour;

    public function dance() {
        echo "elephpant dances!\n";
        return true;
    }
}
```

Thankyou in advance ;-)

Comment: You misspelled "elephant" :)

Comment: http://carsonified.com/blog/dev/getting-started-with-oop-php5/

Comment: @jemfinch no, the mascot of PHP is a blue elephant, hence ElePHPant. See Imran's link.

Comment: I am upvoted this question as it of very rare kind here on SO: not  "how can i do" but "I want to understand". And I wish here was more such a questions.

Comment: I'm surprised it's not closed... But yes great question

Answer (score 15, accepted):

It returns the boolean TRUE to whatever called dance(). That's all.

You would have to look at the consuming code to see if it makes something from it.

Comment: Can you elaborate some possible example of such a consuming code? I have tried and fail

Comment: @Shrapnel $hasDanced = $elephpant->dance();

Comment: ...and exit from the function/loop

Answer (score 6):

In that specific piece of code - not very much.

In general however it would be used to return a condition of a validation or code that needs to return either a positive or a negative.

For instance, one would do the following:

```
public function isValidEmail($email) {
    // do work to see if email is valid
    if(/* Condition making it true */)
       return true;
    else
       return false;
}
```

Comment: Uargh! How about `return $isvalid;`?

Comment: The remark by @Mef still holds. In this case `return /* Condition making it true */;` would do the same.

Comment: @Tom - Never denied that, I was simply being overly specific

Answer (score 3):

because it's `TRUE`, elephpant does dance ;)

Comment: But could I just call the function dance() and it would dance regardless of if it returned true or false?

Answer (score 1):

Sometimes a method/function returns a boolean value to indicate if the operation was succesfull. In the given example it always returns "TRUE".

The calling code can then act upon succesfull completion of the code

`if(dance()) echo "succes"  else echo "fails"`

Answer (score 1):

You can read more about `return` here: http://www.php.net/return

There are few interesting applications of `return` like returning value from `include`-d file.